# Make error "Makefile:xx: *** missing separator. Stop."

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

Currently, I am trying to compile the program Unzip by Info-Zip as I can't find binaries for Windows anywhere so I decided to try to compile it with the source code they provided. After downloading make through Chocolatey, I ran the command to build the source code: `make`. Anyway it gave me an error on the 47th line

```
PS C:\Users\User\Downloads\unzip60\unzip60> make
Makefile:47: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Here is that segment of the Makefile (starting at the 47th line)

```
!IFNDEF debug
NODEBUG=1
!ENDIF
```

I deleted that segment as it seems like it wasn't needed since it seemed like some option switches I didn't need, but it ended up throwing that error for other similar lines as well.

Could someone tell me why it is showing this error and how to fix it? I Googled it up and it says it has something to do with indents but I'm not sure.

(Note: I didn't write this makefile as I got it from the Internet)

Anyway here is the file if someone needs it for reference: https://pastebin.com/LzE9ua2J

Comment: Make is fussy.  You have blanks where you need tabs.

Comment: the Makefile seems to be written for another version of make than the one you use. gnu make e.g. seems to accept only `ifndef` / `endif` instead of `!IFNDEF` / `!ENDIF` and throws exactly the error message you'e posted otherwise (tested on ubunu 22 with GNU make 4.3)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Line 47 does not have tabs, and no line in their file starts with a space.

Comment: Note that on Windows, you can go a long way without an `unzip` binary.  The file browser can browse right into ZIP files, and from there you can select and extract content via drag&drop.  Alternatively, you should find "Extract All..." as an option on the context menu for each ZIP file.  Those alternatives don't necessarily serve *every* need, but they do serve most common ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax with exclamation mark `!IFNDEF` looks like Microsoft's [`nmake` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/makefile-preprocessing?view=msvc-170). You are trying to use GNU make, which uses [different syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html).

If you don't need these parts, you can try deleting them. But there might be other syntax differences between `nmake` and `make`. So, either use `nmake`, as the author of the makefile intended, or rewrite the makefile to use proper syntax.